# Get data of multiple select fields in form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

i have a form with 2 fields which is having jquery token based input, they can have single or multiple value, what is the way to capture the data from both input fields(which contains multiple values), which i should be able to distinguish based on the input field id. i intend to process this data in php script, so is it possible to get the input directly in ($_POST)

```
<div>
<h2>Include</h2>
    <input type="text" id="include" name="include" />


<h2>Must Have</h2>

    <input type="text" id="must_have" name="must_have" />

    <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

jquery script to view the data when u hit the submit button. (it is currently showing me the data of include field only (example:- k1,k2,k3)) but it is not showing me for must_have field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
        alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
    });
});
```

i am new to jquery, so i dont know exaclty how to process this. please help.

Comment: "so is it possible to get the input directly in ($_POST)" Where else do you think it's going?

Comment: i am using jquery autosuggest multiple token input mechanism in this input field, so it is possible to get the data directly in $_POST or i need to do something else,(to get the data in JS , then pass it to php via JSON)

Comment: all fields within the form, except unchecked checkboxes, get posted

Comment: so if my include field contains (k1,k2,k3),  then i am able to get it via $_POST['include'];  ?

Comment: just use the `<?php var_export($_POST); ?>` in your php script and you will see all data posted :)

Comment: stano is right and to answer your last question: yes

Comment: thanx to poopnoodles , for making me understand the concept, i was stupid to think of jquery to process the data. i used var_dump, and i can get all those input..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type=button]").click(function () {
var input1 = $("#include").val();
 var input2 = $("#must_have").val();
    alert("Would submit: " + input1 + "&" + input2);
});
});
```

Comment: this thing works. thank a lot, Now i am considering can i directly use this data in php, without touching Jquery ? or can i directly take the data input in PHP variable?

Comment: umm, What do you mean? Tell me, do you want to process two fields value on the same page with only using PHP or JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use each to iterate on input text elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").each(function(i,elt){alert("Would submit: " + elt.val());});
    });
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle is a great tool, i forgot it :)